# Crystal Report. Change text in details section

Tags: crystal-reports

Is there a way that I can change the text field in my Details section.

something like this

```
if ({tb_Output.Description}) = "NARUTO" then 
    "ANIME"
else
    "CARTOON"
```

I tried this code but it says "The formula result must be boolean".

Comment: You can't change text field. Use 'normal' formula field instead.

Comment: i will agree with @Arov, add a formula field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that by writing this formula by going `right-click -> Format Field`

[image]

and it works for me.

Hope it helps (don't know on which event you wrote your formula)

Answer (score 0):

I would place a formula field in the details section with

`if ({tb_Output.Description}) = "NARUTO" then 
   "ANIME"
else
   "CARTOON"`

Comment: It's literally the same formula as it's on the question. What's the purpose of your answer?